# Connection Refused Error Hadoop Mac

Tags: java, macos, hadoop, jvm

I am trying to install Hadoop. I installed almost everything, all those XML document editing and stuff. I've also installed Java and I'm pretty sure I've done it correctly. When I give the `$hstart` command (I've configured it with an alias for starting hadoop) I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs: line 309: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs: line 309: exec: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directory
Starting namenodes on []
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-TejasBelvalkar-namenode-Tejass-iMac.local.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs: line 309: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs: line 309: exec: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directory
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-TejasBelvalkar-datanode-Tejass-iMac.local.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs: line 309: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs: line 309: exec: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directory
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs: line 309: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs: line 309: exec: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directory
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-TejasBelvalkar-resourcemanager-Tejass-iMac.local.out
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/yarn: line 335: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/yarn: line 335: exec: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directory
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-TejasBelvalkar-nodemanager-Tejass-iMac.local.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/yarn: line 335: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/yarn: line 335: exec: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Now the way I see it, I think I need to set the path to my jvm installation.

Answer (score 0):

It clearly mentions that

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directory

Which implies that there is problem with your `JAVA_HOME`. (Check that this directory actually exists. If it does, then check the `JAVA_HOME` variable.)

Note: `JAVA_HOME` should not include your `/bin` directory, `%JAVA_HOME%/bin` should be present on your path.

Comment: I saw that and it was very obvious it does not exist. But how should I change it. I did try editing the `hadoop-env.sh` by changing `JAVA_HOME` and `HADOOP_PREFIX` as well as the `.bash_profile` to my java path which I obtained after `$ /usr/libexec/java_home` command. Or I should use one with the `$ which java` command? `$ which java` shows `/usr/bin/java` and `$ /usr/libexec/java_home` shows `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home`. Which one to use?

Answer (score 0):

To run Hadoop locally you must be able to SSH localhost
For ex: `$ ssh localhost`
If you get connection refused, enable Remote login by

```
Preference > Sharing > Remote login (enable this option)
```

Try after enabling this remote login